# GnuPG encrypted file editing with Neovim

Tags: neovim, encryption

Is there a way to open a [GnuPG](https://gnupg.org/) encrypted file with `neovim` so that one can read/edit it and on write the file is re-encrypted?

This is possible via [vim-gnupg](https://github.com/jamessan/vim-gnupg) in classic `vim` but [has not been ported to neovim](https://github.com/jamessan/vim-gnupg/issues/32). I cannot use the `gpg-agent` hack as I do not have `X11` installed on the remote machine I wish to use this on.

Comment: As a workaround - have you tried using `gpg-agent` as suggested by tarruda (NeoVim author) in that thread from Github you linked?

Comment: @dotancohen: Thank you for your bounty! Much appreciated.

Comment: @grodzik I have missed your comment when you made it: no, i cannot use it as I do not have X11 installed on the server I wish to use this on.

Comment: Why would you need X11 for that? if for pinentry - then there's a curses-based one as well.

Comment: @grodzik Because Neovim runs external commands attached to a pipe, instead of attached to the tty as Vim did.  This makes interacting with the pinentry problematic, to say the least.  If you `set shellpipe` in Vim, you'll see similar problems.  I've been contemplating whether it would be better to write a new plugin for neovim, since the current one would need a fair amount of refactoring to work nicely with neovim.

Answer (score 5):

I did a little research and it seems that the only option right now is the one mentioned by @grodzik: you need to configure `gpg-agent`. [Quoting Thiago de Arruda](https://github.com/jamessan/vim-gnupg/issues/32#issuecomment-155081600) (Neovim lead developer):

> I'm a long time vim-gnupg user and have been using it with neovim since day 1. I never had problems because I use gpg-agent which by defaults displays a x11 prompt to get the password (the GPG_TTY warning can be safely ignored).

In the same thread the vim-pgp author has shared his progress on making the plug-in compatible with Neovim. I think it will take a while but lately he has been contributing to Neovim (in fact [the last Neovim commit is authored by him](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/108d54bbd455635fc29541eb4bae4b9f3318aafb)) so it's just matter of time.

Comment: I encrypted a file in `vim 8.1.3741` but `nvim v0.6.1` cannot open and decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the solution from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mrash/0f12560983a8c2888c5f) with Vim for years, so when I moved to NeoVim, I translated it to Lua, and it still works:

```lua
local gpgGroup = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('customGpg', { clear = true })

-- autocmds execute in the order in which they were defined.
-- https://neovim.io/doc/user/autocmd.html#autocmd-define

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'BufReadPre', 'FileReadPre' }, {
    pattern = '*.gpg',
    group = gpgGroup,
    callback = function ()
        -- Make sure nothing is written to shada file while editing an encrypted file.
        vim.opt_local.shada = nil
        -- We don't want a swap file, as it writes unencrypted data to disk
        vim.opt_local.swapfile = false
        -- Switch to binary mode to read the encrypted file
        vim.opt_local.bin = true

        vim.cmd("let ch_save = &ch|set ch=2")
    end
})

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'BufReadPost', 'FileReadPost' }, {
    pattern = '*.gpg',
    group = gpgGroup,
    callback = function ()
        vim.cmd("'[,']!gpg --decrypt 2> /dev/null")

        -- Switch to normal mode for editing
        vim.opt_local.bin = false

        vim.cmd('let &ch = ch_save|unlet ch_save')
        vim.cmd(":doautocmd BufReadPost " .. vim.fn.expand("%:r"))
    end
})

-- Convert all text to encrypted text before writing
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'BufWritePre', 'FileWritePre' }, {
    pattern = '*.gpg',
    group = gpgGroup,
    command = "'[,']!gpg --default-recipient-self -ae 2>/dev/null",
})
-- Undo the encryption so we are back in the normal text, directly
-- after the file has been written.
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'BufWritePost', 'FileWritePost' }, {
    pattern = '*.gpg',
    group = gpgGroup,
    command = 'u'
})
```

([gist](https://gist.github.com/traut/cd19ae2817ab13e0bade1f8a9995029f))

It is far from optimal, and I'm open to suggestions for improving it!

Comment: You might look at how zip editing works by using autocommands called (I think) BufWriteCmd and another Cmd for reading (?). That might save you some trouble.